# Como solicitar uma reanálise referente a adição de TAGS não aceita em uma edição?

Tags: suporte, tags

Fiz a edição da pergunta "[Como converter um int em dois bytes em C/C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11641/como-converter-um-int-em-dois-bytes-em-c-c)" Adicionando um tag MicroControlador-32bits, para contextualizar melhor a pergunta já que tenho visto respostas relativas a este assunto sendo respondidas como fora de contexto, porém a tag não foi aceita.

Mas com justificado é fundamental a existências das seguintes tags para melhor contextualizar temas de programação relacionadas a MicroControladores:

- MicroControlador
- MicroControlador-8bits (Similares PIC e AVR)
- MicroControlador-16bits (Similares MSP430 e PIC16)
- MicroControlador-32bits (Similares AVR32, ARM, PIC32)

Comment: Eu fui um dos que rejeitei, e rejeitei porque não achei a TAG relevante para a questão. É como colocar Android-Studio numa pergunta sobre programação em Android.

Comment: Bem no caso a questão se trata de microcontrolador e não há nenhuma tag que relata tal contexto.

Comment: Sim mas acho que essa tag não ia trazer valor a pergunta

Comment: Mesmo a pergunta sendo sobre Microcontrolador?
acho estranho este critério.

Comment: Eu posso-te fazer uma pergunta em que esteja a usar PHP e não seja preciso a tag PHP porquê não vai ajudar em nada quem vai responder.

Answer (score 1):

Não participei da análise, mas ao que parece a pergunta realmente não tem a ver com controladores e sim com manipulação de bits na linguagem C.

Note que, embora a pergunta contextualize que o AP está usando microcontroladores, a informação é irrelevante para qualquer uma das respostas, as quais, aliás, servem para qualquer plataforma.

Sobre as tags citadas, realmente não sei se valeria a pena ter uma granularidade dessas. Me inclino a achar que não, pois hardware não faz parte do foco do SOpt e não há uma quantidade relevante de perguntas sobre o tema.

Comment: Luiz, veja a primeira frase da pergunta: "Eu recebo os dados de um sensor de temperatura em um microcontrolador que tem um conversor AD de 10 bits."

ele cita claramente que o código é para ser usado em um microcontrolador.

Comment: Sobre as Tags mesmo sendo programação para embarcados o SOpt será restritivo? portando questões de programação no Arduino não serão consideradas dentro do foco do site?

Comment: Se eu pedir ajuda para imprimir uma linha no console de uma nave espacial, preciso colocar uma tag "spaceship" para isso? No meu entendimento, manipulação de bits sempre será igual na linguagem.

Comment: Arduino tem uma tag somente. E mesmo assim faz mais sentido se a pergunta for relacionada a uma API específica.

Comment: Sem dúvida Luiz, concordo com você, mas para quem conhece de microcontrolador, sabe que há nuances que muitas vezes são válidas a serem consideradas, e ajudaria muito aqueles que gostariam de focar no tema, podendo selecionar perguntas/resposta pelo assunto. Claro Spaceshiip não seria tanto o caso, eu por exemplo eu estou estudando DTN e nem por isso pretendo criar um tópico para este tema quando vier a discutir programação neste caso, mas não nego que acho interessante.

Comment: Note que estou apenas dando minha opinião e, ao mesmo tempo, explicar porque sua edição foi rejeitada. O que poderia mudar isso seria um outro ponto de vista de mais pessoas da comunidade.

Comment: Vamos esperar a manifestação de mais pessoas amanhã, agora é meio tarde.

Comment: Eu percebo em alguns lugares ligado a programação desktop e web, uma certa resistência com o advento da programação para microcontroladores ter crescido tanto. Não acho que o SOpt deva se fechar a este seguimento, pelo menos até o momento que se possa ter uma nova comunidade para embarcardos na língua portuguesa.

Comment: Delfino, concordo que algumas vezes há resistência, principalmente quando o AP pede ajuda em algo que não é bem programação. Mas em nenhum momento eu quis dizer que o site não aceita ou não quer aceitar perguntas sobre microcontroladores. O único problema grande que enfrentamos é isso que eu acabei de falar, isto é, perguntas que não envolvam programação. O segundo problema, que ocorre ainda em outras áreas, é justamente esta discussão, ou seja, se devemos colocar uma tag específica numa pergunta cujo conteúdo não se restringe aquela tag.

Comment: Realmente nesta questão de sair fora do tema programação é não é bom, nem mesmo é a intenção. Mas sem dúvida que o tema programação para microcontroladores é um tema muito rico, e se bem abordado aqui, será sem duvida favorável para muitos que falam a língua portuguesa e não se sente a vontade para expor suas dúvidas no SOen, ou SE.eletronics. Bem sei que tenho sido insistente neste assunto, mas acredito muito que vai dar certo.

Comment: @Delfino Eu concordo com o utluiz neste ponto, acho a tag desnecessária. Assim como é desnecessário marcar com [eclipse] um monte de pergunta que tem por aí e na verdade é sobre [java], só porque a pessoa está usando o Eclipse e não sabe onde termina a linguagem e começa a IDE. Em relação a programação embarcada, nada contra, muito pelo contrário.

Comment: @bfavaretto, eu concordo quando se fala marcar eclipse para programação java, mas é importante ficar atento que há nuances (repito) que precisam ser consideradas quando se programa para microcontroladores, em especial com pouca memória, portanto marcar questões de programação em C, quando se trata de um ambiente tão limitado é muito relevante. Por exemplo não seria certo eu diferenciar que estou desenvolvendo em C para Windows ou Linux? porque não Microcontroladores em especial 8bits?

Comment: @Delfino Não discordo disso, existem sim casos em que a arquitetura é relevante e deva ser indicada numa tag. Posso estar errado, mas nessa pergunta específica eu achei a tag extra dispensável, o que não quer dizer que ela não seja válida em nenhuma pergunta.

Comment: Olhando superficialmente até concordo que não seja preciso, mas acho relevante para auxiliar a encontrar perguntas que sejam relevantes ao tema. E nisso sem dúvida as tags são fundamentais, ela não ajuda a responder, ajuda a encontrar a pergunta e até mesmo respostas.

Comment: @Delfino os moderadores explicaram muito melhor que eu o porquê de ter rejeitado a tag. Mas fica ai uma boa pergunta a qual eu não sei responder, será relevante adicionar este tipo de tag para auxiliar a encontrar perguntas que sejam relevantes ao tema?

Comment: De onde estou, sempre acho muito útil ter o conteúdo organizado, taxonomicamente, usando as tags corretas assim identificando os contextos. Se a pergunta está no contexto de microcontrolador (mesmo que no segundo plano), ainda acho válido ter a tag, mas claro não quer dizer que se eu programo para a protoboard Arduino, que tenha que também colocar a TAG ArduinoIDE, a não ser que meu objetivo seja desenvolver algo novo para a IDE do Arduino, e neste caso realmente também é bobagem eu colocar a tag Microcontrolador, só porque tal problema está ligado a um outro problema que usa microcontrolador.

Comment: O meu entendimento é que as tags servem principalmente para a organização do conteúdo, isto é, para facilitar que pessoas interessadas em um assunto as encontrem. Como o @Delfino menciona, é uma questão de taxonomia. O exemplo de *Spaceship* é lúdico, mas se houvessem muitas perguntas sobre problemas que ocorrem em naves espaciais, a tag teria no mínimo a utilidade de facilitar encontrar questões relacionadas. Isso pode fazer a diferença para alguém que está com uma dúvida nesse contexto.

Comment: Além do mais, o mesmo argumento de "muito específico" deveria então servir para as tags [tag:int] ou [tag:byte], não? Talvez seja uma questão de como se enxerga a função das tags. Pra mim, elas são palavras-chave, que facilitam encontrar o conteúdo. E nesse sentido, uma tag "MicroControlador" não seria ruim (muito embora ir além disso, com MicroControlador-8Bits e etc, pareça mesmo desnecessário).